# Autocomplete form error: Uncaught TypeError: data.match is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with React and trying to figure out how to return data in an Autocomplete form from a JSON

this is the data

```
const falsyData = [{
    'Hello': {
      'what I do'       : 'you just say Hello',
      'which language'  : 'english'
    },
    'Travel': {
      'Etymology' : 'The origin of the word "travel" is...',
      'Purpose'   : 'include recreation'
    },
    'Gambling': {
      'Gamble'  : 'Gambling is the wagering of money...',
      'Origins' : 'Many popular games played in...'
    }
  }];

  render () {
    return (
      <Grid>
            <TextField
                onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
                onKeyUp={this._changeInput.bind(this)}
                value={this.state.value} />
            {!!this.state.value.length &&
              <Row>
                <Column>  
                 //HERE I PRINT THE RESULTS OF THE SEARCH
                  <p>{this.state.result}</p>
                </Column>                              
              </Row>
            }
      </Grid>
    );
  }

  _matchData = (input) => {
    let reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
    return falsyData.map(function(data) {
      if (data.match(reg)) {
        return data;
      }
    });
  }

  _changeInput = (val) => {
    let autoCompleteResult = this._matchData(this.state.value);
    if (autoCompleteResult.length) {
      this.setState({result: autoCompleteResult.join(' ')});
    };
  }

  _onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
```

I need to filter the data, lets say that the user types in **A**, so in `<p>{this.state.result}</p>` I want to see everything with the letter **A**.

For more specific: if the user types *hello*, I want to see `hello` from `falsyData` with their attributes and properties.

**BTW**

everytime I type in the search bar, this is what I get in the browser console

> Uncaught TypeError: data.match is not a function

Answer (score 1):

`falsyData` is an array of objects. In this block of code:

```
return falsyData.map(function(data) {
  if (data.match(reg)) {
    return data;
  }
});
```

You're mapping over objects, so `data` doesn't have a `match` function, because it isn't a string.

Depending on what you want to match on, change this to match string values within your objects. For example, if you just wanted to match on the outer object's key:

```
return falsyData.map(function(data) {
  for (var key in data) {
    if (key.match(reg)) {
      return key;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: oh! ok, so what should I do then ?

Comment: with this method: in `<p>{this.state.result}</p>` all I am getting is `[object Object]`

Comment: is because you are returning `data` and it is `key` instead

Comment: it is not working as I mentioned in the question. It is returning only one criteria, if you put `H` it returns only `Hello` and not all the things with `H`

Comment: If you want to search iteratively through all of the keys and values of `falsyData`, that's a different problem. You'll have to work on your `map` function so that it iterates not just on the outer objects' keys but the inner objects' keys as well

Comment: what you recommend me, only do this: if I type in `A`, all I get is the first outer Object key. So in this case it is `travel`, and it is not returning `gambling` which also contains an `A`. I can work with the outer objects key also.